# QLCDNumber and unsigned int

Tags: qt5, qlcdnumber

As far as I see, QLCDNumber can only display signed integers. I want to display content of processor registers, which are typically unsigned. Is there any hacking to display unsigned integers?

Comment: @Murphy I do not think it would change anything. Finally, only display(int num) exists, no display(unsigned int num).

Comment: Read the reference of `QLCDNumber`. Try my suggestion. Then come back. Please.

Answer (score 1):

`QLCDNumber` also accepts strings (within a limited character set). Try formatting the value as `QString` before passing it to `QLCDNumber::display()`.

Comment: QLCDNumber has methods setXXXMode(), that is what I prefer. When following your suggestion, I need to re-code manually that internal machinery, and use  QLCDNumber in string-only mode. I think it is not quite in the spirit of object-orientation. Maybe the simplest solution is to subclass, with a new method. I just wanted to know, if someone else faced the problem.